# How to remove Clustered Index scan

Tags: sql, database

The SQL EP plan showing clustered index scan. but the primary key column already have clustered index. Hope will help this Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(KEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CODE VARCHAR(50), 
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(254),
ACTIVE BIT,CONSTRAINT [PK_KEY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (KEY ASC) 
WITH (PAD_IDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCAKS=ON,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCK=ON) [TD]) 
        ON [TD]INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,'ASS','DESC',1) 

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(2,'PRO','PROP',1)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(3,'COL','CLLECTION',1)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(4,'NOA','NOA',0)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(5,'NOPA','NOPA',1)
```

Actual Query :

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM T1 WHERE KEY=4
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. This is a product specific question.

Comment: syntax looks like sql server .are you sure ,its mysql

Comment: it's sql server 2014.

Comment: @user7399003:you should not get a scan for the data you provided,is this just a sample data

Comment: yes, Actually this query is using as a subquery of main select query. and one more thing the where condition is another table of column in place of 4 (changed to subquery instead of left join).